absolute value of bounded operators and norm inequality
Let $x,y \in B(H)$ be bounded operators over a Hilbert space. We define $\left|x\right| = \sqrt{x^*x}$ where $\sqrt{x^*x}$ is the unique positive operator $z$ such that $z^2 = x^*x$.
Unfortunately, some properties of this absolute value are not intuitive, for instance, $\left|xy\right| \not= \left|x\right|\left|y\right|$ or according to this MO answer, the triangle inequality also fails.
My question: Is the inequality $$\left|xy\right| \leq \|x\|_{B(H)} \left|y\right|$$ true?
It seems at least possible since both operators are positive. I tried to prove it and failed, but I cannot find a counterexample.

This is true. Indeed,
$$|xy|^2 = y^\ast x^\ast xy \leq \|x\|^2 y^\ast y = (\|x\||y|)^2$$
It is a general fact that in a $C^\ast$-algebra, $0 \leq a \leq b$ implies $a^{1/2} \leq b^{1/2}$, so the above implies $|xy| \leq \|x\||y|$.

The general fact I cited can be found as Theorem 2.2.6 in Murphy’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory”, for example.

Also note that $|yx| \leq |x||y|$ is not true. For example, $x = e_{12}$, $y = e_{21}$ gives a counterexample.
